# Linked list value being changed

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Relevant code:

Constant Def:

```
#define MAX_NAME_LEN 15 /* Maximum length of any attribute or relation is 15. */
```

Struct Def:

```
typedef struct schnode {
char name[MAX_NAME_LEN + 1]; /* The name of the attribute. */
char type; /* The type of the attribute ('S' or 'I'). */
int len; /* The length of the attribute. */
struct schnode *next; /* A pointer to the next node. */
} SCHNODE;
```

Variable Def:

```
FILE *schemafile; /* A text file. */
SCHNODE *head = NULL; /* Head of the linked list. */
SCHNODE *ptrnode = NULL; /* A variable node in the linked list. */
SCHNODE *p = NULL; /* A variable node in the linked list. */
SCHNODE *tail = NULL; /* Tail of the linked list. */
char *attr_name; /* Holds the name of the current attribute. */
char *attr_type; /* Holds the current attribute type (S or I). */
int attr_len; /* Holds the current attribute length. */
int attr_loc = 0; /* Attribute location in respect to the tuple. */
int i; /* Index for loops. */
char attr_match = 0; /* 1 if the attribute is valid, 0 otherwise. */
```

Constant Def:

```
#define BUFFER_START_SIZE 20
#define BUFFER_INC_SIZE 10
```

NextLine Function:

```
char* NextLine (FILE *f) {
int size = BUFFER_START_SIZE;
char *buf; //buffer storing current line as a char array
int i = 0; //index for array
int c; //a character

if (f == NULL){ //check if the file pointer is NULL
    printf("Unable to find the file.\n"); fflush(stdout);
    return NULL; //nothing to read, so return NULL
}

if((c = getc(f)) == EOF) //check if the first 'char' in the line is EOF
    return NULL; //if so, line is empty, so return NULL

if((buf = (char *) malloc(size)) == NULL){ //make room for the buffer
    printf("Failed to create buffer.\n"); fflush(stdout); }

buf[0] = (char) c; //put the first char into the buffer string
i = 1; //and increment the index

while(1){
    while(i < size){ //loop through the buffer char array
        if((c = getc(f)) == '\n'){ //if end of line
            buf[i] = '\0'; //instead put '\0' to terminate string
            return buf; //and return the completed string
        }
        buf[i] = (char) c; //otherwise, just keep copying the characters
        i++; //increment the index
    }

    //IF REACHED THIS POINT, LINE IS TOO LONG TO FIT IN BUFFER -> REALLOC
    size += BUFFER_INC_SIZE;
    if((buf = (char*) realloc(buf,size)) == NULL){ //make buffer bigger
        printf("Unable to realloc memory.\n"); fflush(stdout); }
    //loop and continue adding chars from where you left off
}
}
```

Executed Code:

```
for (i = 0; i < num_attr; i++) {
    if ((i > 0) && !attr_match) attr_loc += attr_len;
    attr_name = NextLine(schemafile);
    attr_name = strtok(attr_name, " \t\n");
    attr_type = strtok(NULL, " \t\n");
    attr_len =  atoi(strtok(NULL, " \t\n"));

    /* Construct linked list of schema file data. */
    /* If empty: */
    if (head == NULL) {
        if ((head = (SCHNODE*) malloc(sizeof(SCHNODE))) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unable to Malloc space.\n");
            return;
        }
        strcpy(head->name, attr_name);
        head->type = attr_type[0];
        head->len = attr_len;
        head->next = NULL;
    }

    /* If the list already has a head defined: */
    else {
        /* Start from the head if tail is NULL (only 1 element) otherwise start from tail. */
        if(tail == NULL) ptrnode = head;
        else ptrnode = tail;
        /* Malloc space for the tail node. */
        if ((tail = (SCHNODE*) malloc(sizeof(SCHNODE))) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unable to Malloc space.\n");
            return;
        }
        strcpy(tail->name, attr_name);
        tail->type = attr_type[0];
        tail->len = attr_len;
        tail->next = NULL;
        /* Insert tail node at the end. */
        ptrnode->next = tail;
        if (strcmp(tail->name, "Instr") == 0)
            p = tail;
        if (p != NULL) printf("%d: %s\n", i, p->name);
    }
```

Input:

```
CName  S  25
CId    S  8
Instr  S  10
Credits I  4
```

Output:

```
2: Instr
3: Insur
```

No other values are changed (as far as I can tell). Can someone explain why this particular value is always altered? (Instr -> Insur). I just want the entry that I read (Instr) to stay the same throughout the entire process of reading.

Comment: I have one question. In your implementation, `strcpy(head->name, attr_name);` I am not clear who is allocating the space for `name` field of your data structure. So, when you `strcpy`, I feel that there is a potential memory corruption. Am I missing some point here? Can you confirm if you face the same issue with `name` being an `array` instead of a `pointer`?

Comment: Is it necessary to use *all of this code* in your minimal, compilable testcase? The idea is to provide us enough code so that the problem sticks out like a sore thumb. Make a copy of your project, call it your testcase and start reducing it. For example, replace the body of NextLine with `char *foo = malloc(256); fgets(foo, 256, stdin); return foo;`. If the problem disappears, then the problem must be in your NextLine function. Give us that function to analyse. ...

Comment: @ICantNameMe .. can you try one small experiment where the 4th element is _not_ `Credits I  4`, but something like this `PId I  4`. Do you still see the issue with this input data also? I am suspecting your `realloc` logic and hence, this request.

Comment: ... Abstract repetitive code into separate functions. For example, `SCHNODE *node_alloc(char *name, char type, int len, SCHNODE *next) { SCHNODE *node = malloc(sizeof *node); node->name = malloc(strlen(name) + 1); strcpy(node->name, name); node->type = type; node->len = len; node->next = next; }` and test that the abstracted away functions work, then you only have to test them once and use them the same every time, eg: `head = node_alloc(attr_name, attr_type[0], attr_len, NULL); tail = head;` and `tail->next = node_alloc(attr_name, attr_type[0], attr_len, NULL); tail = tail->next;`.

Comment: Question already fixed with the first comment, and sorry for overloading you guys with code, I guess I just wanted to make sure people knew everything possible so that I could figure out the error. Anyway, the problem was that `char *name` was defined as a pointer, not a static buffer, so it caused memory corruption when using `strcpy` or something... It was fixed by changing name to `char name[MAX_NAME_LEN+1];`

Comment: @ICantNameMe ok shall I post this as an answer?

Comment: Yes, go ahead, since it worked

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is unlikely to help other visitors to Stack Overflow in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your program, the `name` field of your data structure is defined to be a `pointer`. Hence, when you `strcpy`, there will be memory corruption as no space has been allocated to the `pointer`. Hence, either `malloc` a space for `name` for every node or define `name` to be an array of `n` elements.